# Tradingview - How to use multiple input type=source

Tags: pine-script, trading

I'm currently trying to set up a script to generate conditional alerts whenever another script displays several specific data points.

input(type=source) works no problem, but as soon as I try to add more than one source input, it stops working all together.

I'm on a Premium Tradingview plan and can't find anything in the pinescript documentation to explain this limitation. From digging around, the best reasoning I could find is that their system couldn't handle everyone stacking scripts on scripts on scripts..

The easiest solution would be to add the conditional alert to the script I'm trying to pull from, but in this case I don't have access to that source code.

Does anyone know of a work around to pull multiple data points from a single source?

Otherwise I guess my solution is to try and recreate the source and build the alerts there?

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible. Pinescripts are limited to only 1 external source.

Answer (score 1):

Pine scripts are limited to 1 external source; input.source

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of the Premium plan, 24 external sources should be available to you.

[image]

Comment: Bit late to this, but this is reference to another functionality, ie.
https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/new-feature-8211-apply-an-indicator-to-another-indicator-1844/

Adding multiple `input.source()`'s in a custom indicator/strategy is different, and appears to be limited to 1 :(